# How to store filtered data based on side bar

Tags: r, shiny

I want to store the filtered data from two side bar in my shiny app for future analysis. Here is the original data frame in my app. There are two data frame. Called Dataset1 and Dataset2, for each Datasets, there are four column, they are Participant, Race_ID, Score, Organizations. Below is an example of the dataset.

```
Participant | Race_ID | Score | Organization
P1 | R1 | 9.1 | O1
P1 | R2 | 7.5 | O1
P1 | R3 | 6.7 | O1
P1 | R4 | 8.0 | O2
P1 | R5 | 7.8 | O2
P2 | R1 | 9.9 | O1
P2 | R2 | 8.0 | O1
P2 | R3 | 7.7 | O1
P2 | R4 | 4.0 | O2
P2 | R5 | 6.2 | O2
```

The first side bar contains Dataset1 and Dataset2, the second side bar contains the P1--PX which is the participant ID in each dataset. I want to store the filtered data from these two side bar. For example, if the user choose Dataset1 in the first side bar and P2 in the second side bar, the result filtered data will be like this:

```
Participant | Race_ID | Score | Organization
P2 | R1 | 9.9 | O1
P2 | R2 | 8.0 | O1
P2 | R3 | 7.7 | O1
P2 | R4 | 4.0 | O2
P2 | R5 | 6.2 | O2
```

I will only display the columns of P2. Below is my code so far:

```
Dataset1 <- read.csv("XXXX")
Dataset2 <- read.csv("XXXX")
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Races Visualization"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("Dataset","Please select a dataset to dispaly:",choices = c("Dataset1", "Dataset2")),
            uiOutput("Participant")
            ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
           plotOutput("barplot")
           )
    )
)
        
    


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(output, input)({
    var <- reactive({
        switch(input$Dataset,
               "Dataset1" = unique(Dataset1$Participant),
               "Dataset2" = unique(Dataset2$Participant)
               )
    })
    
        
    output$Participant <- renderUI({
selectInput("Participant", "Select the Participant", choices = var())
    })

})

filtered_data <- input$Dataset %>% filter(unique(input$Dataset))
    
output$barplot <- renderPlot({
        attach(get(input$Dataset))
        
    })
    
 

   


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to store the filtered data as filtered_data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues:

- a reactive (as `input`) can only be accessed in a reactive context (e.g. `reactive` or `observeEvent`)
- `input$Dataset` only contains the information which dataset is selected, but not the dataset itself

You can use an `actionButton`/`observeEvent` to store the selected data as `.Rds` in the directory where the app is saved (or you could specify a different path):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

Dataset1 <- mtcars %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Participant")
Dataset2 <- mtcars %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Participant")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Races Visualization"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Dataset","Please select a dataset to dispaly:",choices = c("Dataset1", "Dataset2")),
      uiOutput("Participant"),
      actionButton(inputId = "store", "Store the selection")
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("barplot")
    )
  )
)




# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(output, input){
  var <- reactive({
    switch(input$Dataset,
           "Dataset1" = unique(Dataset1$Participant),
           "Dataset2" = unique(Dataset2$Participant)
    )
  })
  
  
  output$Participant <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Participant", "Select the Participant", choices = var())
  })
  



  observeEvent(input$store, {
    
    if (input$Dataset == "Dataset1") {
      filtered_data <- Dataset1 %>% filter(Participant == input$Participant)
    } else {
      filtered_data <- Dataset2 %>% filter(Participant == input$Participant)
    }
    
    saveRDS(filtered_data, paste0(input$Dataset, "_", input$Participant, ".Rds"))
  })

output$barplot <- renderPlot({
  attach(get(input$Dataset))
  
})
}






# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```